# What $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ stands for in number theory?

Tags: number-theory, notation

I think that is a very simple/silly question but i can't find the meaning of the asterisk in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

I'm trying to understand some basic concepts in **number theory**, while studying **cryptography** (for example yesterday i came across these [lectures](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/)) and I've been seeing this symbolism.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_n = {0, 1, ..., n-1}$, but what the extra $'*'$ stands for?

Until today, i knew that the asterisk above a set of numbers "means" the same set with $'0'$ excluded, but i don't think it's the same in this case.

Also i found that it may mean [the non-negative integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Star.html) of the set, but (at least in my lectures), the $\mathbb{Z}_n$ already doesn't have negative integers.

In every cryptography - number theory lectures/course i've came across they just write it down without exlain it, but it really confuses me.

Any help?

Comment: It likely stands for the multiplicative group of units of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. That is, the group consisting of elements of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ that are coprime to $n$, with multiplication as its operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stands for the set of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ which are invertible modulo $n$. In particular, if $n$ is prime, then (and only then) $\mathbb{Z}_n^*=\mathbb{Z}_n\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Basically it refers to the invertible elements in the group, which in this case are those who are relatively prime to n.